# WHERE IN clause

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, where-clause

I'm working in MVC3 project. I was browsing for a while and trying several examples but I could not get it working.

I need to get a list of record from `OrderForm` table whose `DeptID` are in another list I already have got.

I'm aware that I need to use `Contains()` replacing `IN` SQL clause, but every example that I could read are doing this in the same way

```
.Where(ListOfDepartments.Contains(q.DeptID))
```

This is my method at the controller, which obviously is not working:

```
public ActionResult ValidOrders(string installation, string orderpriority, string stockclass, string validity)
{
    int instID = System.Convert.ToInt32(installation);
    int orderpriorityID = System.Convert.ToInt32(orderpriority);
    int stockclassID = System.Convert.ToInt32(stockclass);
    string period = validity;

    try
    {
        var departments = dba.Department
                            .Where (a => a.InstID == instID);

        var valid = dba.OrderForm
            .Where(q => q.FormType == 3 
                && q.FormStatus == 2 
                && q.OrderPriority.OrderPriorityID == orderpriorityID
                && q.StockClassID == stockclassID
                && departments.Contains(q.DeptID));              

        return View(valid.ToList());
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you getting any exception

Comment: You should join with `Department`.

Comment: I think you need to add a `Select` to the end of your departments query and only retrieve the ids you want to compare `DeptID` to.

Comment: What's the type of `departments`? You might need to do `departments.Select(d => d.ID).Contains(q.DeptID)` to pull the IDs out of your list of departments.

Comment: No. VS2010 is underlining "departments.Contains(q.DeptID)", so it's wrong syntax. Removing this clause i get the list (incorrect list) without problems.

Comment: Yeah, the reason it's underlining that is because you're asking if a collection of type `Department` contains an entity of type `int` (or whatever your IDs are). Adding `.Select(d => d.ID)` will give you a collection of the correct type, so your `.Contains()` will work. Alternatively, you could do the `.Select(d => d.ID)` earlier, where you do `var departments = ...`. Because LINQ will generate the whole query and then call the database when you evaluate (eg. by using `ToList()`) the two are more or less equivalent.

Comment: @anaximander that was exactly what was happening. Now is fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need a list of `int`, not `Department`.

```
var departments = dba.Department
                            .Where (a => a.InstID == instID)
                            .Select(d => d.Id);//Id is a guess, it maybe another property name
                            //.ToList();
```

Comment: If you leave off the `ToList` wouldn't this result in one query to the DB instead of two?

Comment: Thank you so much @RaphaëlAlthaus !! Now is working perfectly. I tried with `.ToList()` and without it. Both options works.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Thanks to you for the solution! :)